# Visual Studio Code jQuery Selector Preview on Hover

Tags: jquery, css, visual-studio-code, jquery-selectors

When I hover on a CSS selector, I can see the preview of what it selects (below, first image). I'd like it to work on jQuery selectors as well. Is there a way?

I searched through Stack Exchange communities and googled, but I couldn't find anything.

[image: hover]

[image: hoverjquery]

[image: hoverjquery2]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript

Comment: I read that doc and configured `jsconfig.json`, Automatic Type Acquisition works but the exact feature I want doesn't work. Maybe I am missing something @Anant-Alivetodie?

Comment: I also have not much idea about it.